# How do I beat "Prize for the Reckless"?

Tags: vvvvvv

[image]

Now I know that the top platform is split and if I dissolve one half the other will move back and forth but by the time I work my way through all the other screens to get back to the bottom half, the floating panel has reappeared, trapping my ride to the trinket.  What do I do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to make it from the bottom to the top *without touching any checkpoints*.  That way, you can free the sliding platform, die, and respawn below, in position to collect the trinket.

The most important part is that *you must respawn in the same room*.  Else the platforms will reset and you'll be stuck again.

Comment: The important thing to note is that unless you respawn in the same room, the floating platforms reset, hence why you need to avoid the checkpoints in the first place.

Comment: And this is why it's called "Prize for the *Reckless*"

Answer (score 0):

Take the checkpoint at the bottom. Now, head to the top of the room without  taking any other checkpoints. Now, get the block that breaks when you're on it. Once the moving block is on the side with the checkpoint. Run into the spikes purposefully. Wait for the moving block to reach you. Run on it. Flip down when you're above the trinket. Get it! Flip up at any time. Move on to what you're doing.